# SQL- How to combine 3 tables to get this result?

Tags: mysql

The SNO seems to be misdirecting
So, I simplified the question even further

```
--creation
CREATE TABLE LAB (JOB_ID int, LAB_ID VARCHAR(50));
CREATE TABLE SPR (JOB_ID int, SPR_ID VARCHAR(50));

--Table 1 data insertion
INSERT INTO LAB (JOB_ID, LAB_ID) VALUES(10, 'LAB_10');
INSERT INTO LAB (JOB_ID, LAB_ID) VALUES(10, 'LAB_20');
INSERT INTO LAB (JOB_ID, LAB_ID) VALUES(10, 'LAB_30');

--Table 2 data insertion
INSERT INTO SPR (JOB_ID, SPR_ID) VALUES(10, 'SPR_10');
INSERT INTO SPR (JOB_ID, SPR_ID) VALUES(10, 'SPR_20');
```

The query I tried

```
SELECT L.JOB_ID, L.LAB_ID, S.SPR_ID
FROM LAB L 
JOIN SPR S ON S.JOB_ID = L.JOB_ID
```

The result I got

JOB_ID  LAB_ID  SPR_ID

10  LAB_10  SPR_20

10  LAB_10  SPR_10

10  LAB_20  SPR_20

10  LAB_20  SPR_10

10  LAB_30  SPR_20

10  LAB_30  SPR_10

The result I need

JOB_ID  LAB_ID  SPR_ID

10  LAB_10  SPR_10

10  LAB_20  SPR_20

10  LAB_30  NULL

Comment: Maybe you can add if the info show in this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bb99c93d33ed473ab0aeab20a4baf5a0) is correct or, when it's not correct what is wrong/incorrect. This should help anyone reading your question to give a good answer to you.

Comment: I thought I was editing the post, sorry but I have to do it again.

Comment: You should have (or define) ar relation ship between `LAB` and`SPR`, maybe something like this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3219bc9f9068de09b3b27426a800bf88)  ( the relationship used is: `RIGHT(l.LAB_ID,2)=RIGHT(s.SPR_ID,2)`)

Comment: @stu pls check the edited question.

Comment: @Luuk should I close this question cause I got the solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY job_id ORDER BY lab_id) rn
          FROM lab ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY job_id ORDER BY spr_id) rn
          FROM spr ),
cte3 AS ( SELECT rn, job_id FROM cte1
          UNION 
          SELECT rn, job_id FROM cte2 )
SELECT cte1.job_id, cte1.lab_id, cte2.spr_id
FROM cte3
LEFT JOIN cte2 ON cte3.rn = cte2.rn AND cte3.job_id = cte2.job_id
LEFT JOIN cte1 ON cte3.rn = cte1.rn AND cte3.job_id = cte1.job_id
```

Comment: Yes, this works. Need to create a virtual RowNumber and use it to combine the records. Thank you very much.

Comment: I was able to apply this concept in my project, and it works fine. Thanks again.